# Regex split by ":{ in java?

Tags: java, regex

basically I have:

```
 String str = "Stream: {"stream":null,"_links":{"self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/tfue","channel":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/tfue"}}";
```

I want to split the str by `":{`
but when I do:

`String[] BuftoStringparts = BuftoString.split("\":{");`

I get below exception:

> java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 1
>   ":{
>    ^

All replies are much appreciated :)

Comment: Looks almost like JSON, any chance of using a JSON parser instead?

Comment: @CertainPerformance, nah, it has nothing to do with json, that was just FYI, but people rather than asking they like clicking buttons :(

Answer (score 1):

The main reason this happens:

> java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 1 ":{ ^

It's because they are special characters in Java regular expressions so you need to use it escaped for the regex, so by following way:

```
String[] BuftoStringparts = BuftoString.split("\":\\{");
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to escape `"` in your JSON String, so the resulting String will be:

```
 String str = "Stream: {\"stream\":null,\"_links\":{\"self\":\"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/tfue\",\"channel\":\"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/tfue\"}}";
```

Now as mentioned by others, you also need to escape regex special characters in your regex.
 You can try your split by following regex:

```
String[] BuftoStringparts = BuftoString.split("\":\\{");
```